# START Cypher query relationship lookup

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Cypher Neo4J query of the following kind:

```
START rel=relationship:relationship_auto_index(user="9d6e7140-f3c3-11e3-927f-1f5ca4210ac7") 
RETURN rel;
```

Do you know know how I filter to return only the rels that have :TO label? I know I could do it otherwise, but I need to use legacy indexing and want to filter through the relationships I got. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypher has a `TYPE` function:

```
START rel=relationship:relationship_auto_index(user="9d6e7140-f3c3-11e3-927f-1f5ca4210ac7") 
WHERE TYPE(rel)='TO'
RETURN rel;
```

Be aware to omit the colon in front of TO as it's not part of the relationship type itself.